# How to limit the number of multiple characters in an input value？

Tags: javascript

I want to limit the number of letters at the beginning and end of the input value (e.g. QQ23F and SG21G) through JavaScript but I found that only one {} can be written in a pattern. Thanks for any help.
Here is my incorrect code:

```
var isValid = true;
  var id=document.getElementById("pid").value;
  if (!id.match(/[A-Za-z]{2}+[0-9]+[A-Za-z]{1}/)) {
      document.getElementById("pidMessage").innerHTML="Your pid format is invalid!";
      isValid = false;
  }
```

Comment: `{2}+` is invalid; did you mean perhaps `{2,}` (for 2 or more)?

Comment: Hi Nick, I just want to have 2 letters only at the starting.

Comment: Then just use `{2}` and get rid of the `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the begging `^` and end `$` signs

```js
  let isValid = true;
  let id=document.getElementById("pid").value;
  if (!id.match(/^([A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+[A-Za-z]{1})$/)) {
      document.getElementById("pidMessage").innerHTML="Your pid format is invalid!";
      isValid = false;
  }
```

And for everyone's sake use `let` not `var`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried this again but the console still says Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Comment: @RyanYan, I updated my code. Please check.

Comment: @RyanYan, Glad to hear that. Please mark that as the answer to the question.